# Google Maps API imposing new quota - will my requests count against the limit?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I listen that google map api is going to be paid. So my question is related to this.

In my website i have one link and on clicking on that link, i have written following code :

```
canvas = window.open("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=some address");
```

I think window.open method send http get request. And this code open the google map in a new tab.

so my question is that since google api is paid now, so does it require any changes in this line or not.

Will this request be counted in 25000 requests of google javascript map api ?

Comment: Where did you hear that Google Maps's API is going to be paid? Link please. I can see no evidence that it's true.

Comment: @Pekka see this link  http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps-compare.html

Comment: There are now usage limits, allowing you to purchase additional quota. Only applies to for-profit sites: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/usage.html

Comment: @olivehour Ah, interesting. They're far from a wholesale "Google map API is nw going to be paid" though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using API in your example, so you don't have to change anything in this case.

Comment: it means the restriction of 25000 requests does not apply to my code and i can use more that this much request

Comment: @Vikas yup. It's just a link, not a real maps embed